# Running a program from its Directory Using Cron

Tags: python, macos, unix

I'm on an OSX machine using UNIX. I have a Python program that I want to run every hour or so, so I've set up a basic cron command in my editor:

```
0 * * * * python Documents/workspace/programfolder/src/ProgramToRun.py
```

I haven't actually tried this yet because I'm already running into issues. I've tried to just run the `python Documents/workspace/programfolder/src/ProgramToRun.py` command from my home directory, but the script fails to find any of the files in its directory that it depends upon. It is as though the program is somehow running in my home directory and cannot find any of its dependencies. If I `cd` into the folder where the program is located and do python `ProgramToRun.py`, it works fine. So my question is how can I get cron to treat this program like I'm running it from its directory? And would the directory I've given even work, or would I need to give something more absolute like /Users/MyName...etc.?

Comment: Just include the cd’ing in the command? Alternatively, make the script safe to be run from anywhere.

Comment: I often use plain shell scripts in a crontab that then bootstrap the real script. It gives you that flexibility to see what's happening also it allows you to change the implementation of your code. It may start off as a python script then change to be a exe or something else. In my shell scripts I often do ``scriptdir=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd)`` or in your case it would be ``cd $(dirname $0)``

Comment: Why are you using `cron` instead of `launchd` on OS X? Just about every piece of documentation that mentions `cron` starts with something like ["Note: Although it is still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of launchd."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW2). If you already know `cron` well, that's a good reason to use it, but otherwise, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this in one of two ways:

**First way**:

`cd` into the dir containing the python script and the dependencies and run it from there as follows:

```
(cd /Users/username/Documents/workspace/programfolder/src/ && python ProgramToRun.py)
```

Here, the parens invoke a "subshell". Think of it like a contiguous session in which all commands are run. The `&&` functions as a `;`, but doesn't execute the next command if the previous command fails

**Second way**:

Add `Documents/workspace/programfolder/src/` to the PYTHONPATH inside `ProgramToRun.py` as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/username/Documents/workspace/programfolder/src/")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For your second way, you are still specifying a relative path, so there is still a dependency on the current directory that the script happens to be run from. I suggest `sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/workspace/programfolder/src"))`.

Comment: Should the same logic be applied if I go with the first option? I.e., since the path I'm cd'ing to is relative, if I'm already in some different directory in UNIX, would the program be able to make sense of this? Or does cron not operate on any instances of terminal that you have open and instead creates a new instance of terminal starting in your home directory?

Comment: `cron` usually runs from the home dir, so you should be fine with that. But thanks for the good catch, @Celada. Updated!

Answer (score 4):

Put this at the top of you script before you start doing relative stuff.

```
import os
scriptdir =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(scriptdir)
```

it also may be a symptom that your script isn't actually trying to resolve paths etc relative to the script in the first place. Scripts shouldn't rely on the user running the script from the same directory as the script.

I usually use `scriptdir` to find stuff relative to the script e.g.

`open(os.path.join(scriptdir, 'data', 'someconfig.cfg'))` instead of  `open(os.path.join('data', 'someconfig.cfg'))`

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, as [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW2) says:

> Although it is still supported, `cron` is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of `launchd`.

If you already know `cron` like the back of your hand from long Unix experience, or you're implementing the same thing on both OS X and Linux, or you have some other good excuse, go ahead and use `cron`. But clearly, that's not the case here.

And if you were using `launchd`, the answer here would be trivial. From the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist):

> **`WorkingDirectory <string>`**
>
> This optional key is used to specify a directory to chdir(2) to before running the job.

Or, if you want to modify the environment used for running the app (e.g., to put its directory into `PYTHONPATH`), that's just as easy.

Here's a sample `launchd.plist` file for running your program every hour:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.ProgramToRun</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>python</string>
        <string>Documents/workspace/programfolder/src/ProgramToRun.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>Documents/workspace/programfolder/src/</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

A lot of old Unix hands will look at this and say, "Wow, that's horribly verbose." And I agree. On the other hand, it's not deprecated. Also, it has additional functionality, its interaction with sleep is well documented and easily configurable, etc. And there are samples and explanations all over the Apple documentation that will tell you how to make this work, while `cron` has basically nothing but the manpage and a few documents that say "If you know what you're doing, go ahead and use it, but we won't help you".

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you don't have that directory in your python path, so that Python can't find the modules that the script is trying to import. Add the folder to your path. You can do something like

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```

In your script file, or better, use the a .pth file in lib/site-packages to include the directory that the script lives in.

Comment: If I go with sys.path.append(), does this only temporarily change my PATH, or is it permanent? Also, what does it do once the path has already been appended? Does it check if it's already there, or am I going to get a PATH file that grows every time I run the program?

Comment: only temporary. If you want to permanently add a directory to the path then append that directory to a .pth file, usually located in lib/site-packages.